# Is there any way to access the parent object in a Cancan nested resource ability?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a nested resource for which I'm using Cancan to do authorization. I need to be able to access the parent object in order to be able to authorize the `:index` action of the child (since no child instance is passed for an `:index` action).

```
# memberships_controller.rb
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  load_and_authorize_resource :org
  load_and_authorize_resource :membership, through: :org
  ..
end
```

ability.rb

```
can [:read, :write], Membership do |membership|
  membership.org.has_member? user
end
```

#### This doesn't work for the :index action

Unfortunately the index action doesn't have any membership instance associated with it and so you can't work your way back up to check permissions.

In order to check the permissions, I need to interrogate the parent object (the org) and ask it whether the current user is a member e.g.

```
# ability.rb
...
can :index, Membership, org: { self.has_member? user }
```

### Cancan almost lets me do this...

Cancan states that you can access the parent's attributes using the following mechanism:
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources#wiki-accessing-parent-in-ability

```
# in Ability
can :manage, Task, :project => { :user_id => user.id }
```

However this just works by comparing attributes which doesn't work for my case.

### How can I access the parent object itself though?

Is there any way to access the parent object itself within the permissions?

Answer (score 5):

I recently faced the same problem and ended up with the following (assuming you have `Org` model):

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_org, only: [:index, :new, :create] # if shallow nesting is enabled (see link at the bottom)
  before_action :authorize_org, only: :index

  load_and_authorize_resource except: :index

  # GET orgs/1/memberships
  def index
    @memberships = @org.memberships
  end

  # ...

private

  def set_org
    @org = Org.find(params[:org_id])
  end

  def authorize_org
    authorize! :access_memberships, @org
  end

end
```

ability.rb:

```
can :access_memberships, Org do |org|
  org.has_member? user
end
```

#### Useful links

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/301

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting

Comment: Interesting, this is almost exactly the same approach that I've taken though I feel uncomfortable with the ad-hoc authorization calls. Like you though I can't see any way around them.

Comment: Good thing to be implemented in https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan since original repo is out of maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do something like this?

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    can :index, Membership, org: {id: user.memberships.map(&:org_id)}
  end
end
```

Comment: (refers to original answer) Kudos, I'm impressed. I'm pretty sure that that does work however it doesn't quite address the question which is how to handle the issue of the index action. It also didn't look at the membership on the attached org itself which is where the org_id is actually specified. Can you update the ability to say `can :index, Membership, org: {id: user.memberships.map(&:org_id)}` and then I'll mark your answer as correct - thank you!

Comment: Actually I've just edited your answer to make it exactly address the question. I hope you don't mind

Comment: Sorry, have just realised that while this addressed the particular question I asked - it doesn't address the original question (how do you access the object) and for me it unfortunately proved not to work (not for lack of being an excellent suggestion) because I have to query the member status to see whether it's active or not. You still get the bounty though!

Comment: Maybe you could use a scope for that on the Member model?